# SQL SELECT query syntax quandry

Tags: sql, select, syntax

I'm using the following syntax for a SQL SELECT query to pull data from multiple tables (Using Sequel Pro):

```
select Study_Results.CASNumber, Study_Results.Dose, Study_Results.Units, Study_Results.Effects, Studies.Species, Studies.Route, Studies.Result, ToxData_References.BriefReference, Studies.Study, Studies.Summary
from Study_Results, Studies, ToxData_References
where Study_Results.ProtocolID = Studies.ProtocolID
AND Studies.Location = ToxData_References.Location
AND Studies.Study = "Local Lymph Node Assay"
order by Study_Results.CASNumber
```

The query runs and finishes without an error, but when I look at the results, there are copies of records with mismatched data---i.e., it seems different records are being combined  incorrectly in the query result.

Question: Is there something wrong with my syntax that is resulting in the mismatched data?

Here's some sample output (actual and expected)

One row is correct:
103694-68-4 10.0000 %   NOE mouse   skin        Symrise,2002c   Local Lymph Node Assay  Under the conditions of the study, the test material is unlikely to be a skin sensitiser.   49523   45957

But a second row I get applies the same Study_Results.CASNumber to data from a different Study_Results.CASNumber:

103694-68-4 10.0000 %   NOE mouse   skin        Symrise,2002c   Local Lymph Node Assay  The application of test material at concentrations of 1%, 3% and 10% w/v in acetone resulted in a greater than 3-fold increase in isotope incorporation at the 3% and 10% w/v concentrations.  Therefore, the test material was shown to be a skin sensitiser, confirming the validity of the protocol used for the study.  49523   45957

The above data actually applies to a different CASNumber.

Comment: Hard to tell. Would you add sample data for the 3 tables, sample of the output you are getting and a sample of the output you expect?

Comment: The defintions of the three tables would help, too. You may not be joining on the correct (or on the whole) foreign/primary keys.

Comment: I think he's still getting a cross join from `Study_Results` and `ToxData_References` since that relationship isn't defined in the `WHERE` clause

Comment: Sure! Here's some sample data. It looks like the query is returning an "extra" incorrect record for each expected/correct record.

Comment: whoops-tried to add too many characters--can I attach a text file to show you the sample output?

Answer (score 2):

It is generally agreed that the modern ANSI syntax is better

```
select Study_Results.CASNumber, Study_Results.Dose, Study_Results.Units, Study_Results.Effects, Studies.Species, Studies.Route, Studies.Result, ToxData_References.BriefReference, Studies.Study, Studies.Summary 
from Study_Results
    inner join Studies on Study_Results.ProtocolID = Studies.ProtocolID 
    inner join ToxData_References on Studies.Location = ToxData_References.Location 
where Studies.Study = "Local Lymph Node Assay" 
order by Study_Results.CASNumber
```

If you find the duplicates are valid, based on your data, you can remove them by adding a `distinct` after the select.

ie:

```
 select distinct Study_Results.CASNumber, ...
```

Comment: Thanks! It turns out that the duplicates are not valid. The "duplicate" record is being pulled in incorrectly--and is associated with another uniqueID.

Comment: Fixed it! Turns out I was missing the most important join condition: AND Studies.CASNumber = Study_Results.CASNumber Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the duplicates is that you have multiple records that match in the tables.  These multiples are occuring in one or both these places:

- Location, between Studies and ToxDataReferences
- Protocol_id, between Studies and Studies_Results

If each table has a unique id, you can get an idea of what is happening by counting the occurrences:

```
select Study_Results.CASNumber,
       count(distinct sr.StudyResultsId),
       count(distinct s.ProtocolId),
       count(distinct tdr.ToxDataReferencesId)
from Study_Results sr inner join
     Studies s
     on sr.ProtocolID = s.ProtocolID inner join
        ToxData_References tdr
     on s.Location = tdr.Location
```

You are probably expecting uniqueness in tables that don't have uniqueness.  Perhaps you are missing a join condition.  Perhaps the data is a bit different from how you understand it.

Comment: Thanks! The sample output I just posted did not post in a way that looks helpful. Can I attach a text file for you to review?

Comment: This is very helpful. The variable that is showing up incorrectly is Study_Results.CASNumber. The query result is providing output that is correctly matched with Study_Results.CASNumber in one case, and then the incorrect duplicate delivers different data but connects it to the incorrect Study_Results.CASNumber

Comment: Fixed it! Turns out I was missing the most important join condition: AND Studies.CASNumber = Study_Results.CASNumber Thanks for your help!